# Tinymce и безопасность

Tags: безопасность, tinymce, php

Внедряю на сайт  визуальный редактор Tinymce, чтобы юзеры могли писать красивые комментарии. Там же есть возможность вставить изображение, указав адрес картинки. Вопрос такой - если этот адрес может быть абсолютно любым, то существует ли возможность у хакера указать там url, который разнесет сайт на кусочки? :)

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос. Вы бы спросили у экспертов по безопасности. Публичный форум — не то место, где вы сможете гарантированно получить квалифицированный совет: в конце-концов, тут могут быть хакеры, которые уговорят вас, что некоторая техника безопасна, и взломают ваш сайт.

Но всё же, ответьте себе на вопросы:

- Что будет, если пользователь вставит `javascript:`-ссылку? Не получите ли вы XSS? Поэкспериментируйте.
- Что будет, если пользователь вставит ссылку на другой MIME-тип, не картинку?

По крайней мере когда-то это было проблемой: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=369814

---

Кстати, попробуйте на нашем сайте вставить в ответ вот такую картинку:

```
![XSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/account/signout/?next=http://hashcode.ru)
```

(работает почему-то только в режиме редактирования).

Comment: @VladD, <img src='javascrip:ссылка' /> - ничего не дает. 

Почему я задал вопрос с меткой php? Что будет, если прописать 

<img src='http:site/evil.php'?

Где evil.php - это вредоносная программа. Запуститься ли она в браузере вместо изображения или нет?

Comment: А как насчёт `<img src="javascript:alert('XSS')"/>`?

Насчёт PHP — depends. Посмотрите, какой MIME-тип отдаст сервер. Если это что-нибудь наподобие `application/php`, браузер пользователя не запустит его на выполнение, а предложит загрузить и сохранить, по идее. Или нет, проэкспериментируйте.

Comment: @@VladD, я об этом же ж, ни javascript:location.href='someSite', ни http://someSite.html - ничего не прокатывает. Т.е. тэг <img> требует только mime тип изображений. Это хорошо, с одной стороны, с другой - я же не знаю мышления хакеров, поэтому и вопрос задал.

Comment: @Deus: вы на скольких браузерах проверяли? Некоторые позволяют: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12658992/276994

---
Там ещё хорошая ссылка: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @VladD, не на всех проверял. Что посоветуете? Слишком сложно проверять все тэги img после отправки сообщения. Достаточно ли будет просто делать str_replace('javascript','', $post)?  На всякий случай?

Comment: Я бы попробовал распарсить URL, и убедиться, что протокол — http. А то мало ли, у `javascript:` были когда-то алиасы, на всё чёрных списков не напасёшься. Кроме того, не факт, что `http:` достаточно. Что будет, например, если вы напишете `<img source="yoursite.org/logout.php">`? А если `source="skype:victim?call"`?

---
Короче говоря, спросите лучше у настоящих экспертов.